# users' Image and File information without disclosing it in the privacy policy

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

i have tried to update an application in the playstore. The update was rejected due to the following reasons:

***Privacy Policy in Play Console**

Your app is uploading users' image and file information without disclosing it in the privacy policy in Play Console.*

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
[Play store response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWVAK.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade this library `com.segment.analytics.android:analytcs`  to [Version 4.10.4](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-android/releases/tag/4.10.4), if you are not using `com.segment.analytics.android:analytcs` then that  means that one of the libraries you are currently using is using it, find this library and update it to the latest version.

then update your app and deactivate all older versions, including testing beta versions.